# VueJS drag and drop [Need a simple CSS fix]

Tags: jquery, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on a project which is based on VueJS and needs a drag & drop + nestable option like I demonstrated below. So far achieved a lot, However, yet, I can't figure out why the recursive function doesn't work well.

Can anyone help me to figure out? JSFiddle also attached at the bottom.

**UPDATE:** I just figure-out, it is only a **CSS** issue. So any CSS expert who can help me on this?

```js
var local = {
  template: '#template-drag',
  name: 'local-draggable',
  props: ['tasks']
};


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
    components: {
        "local-draggable" : local
  },
  data: {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "task 1",
       "tasks": []
    },
    {
      "name": "task 2",
       "tasks": []
    },{
      "name": "task 3",
       "tasks": []
    },
    {
      "name": "task 4",
       "tasks": []
    },
    {
      "name": "task 5",
       "tasks": []
    },
    {
      "name": "task 6",
       "tasks": [
        {
          "name": "task 6.1",
           "tasks": []
        }
       ]
    }
  ]
  },
});
```

```css
.parent{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.dragArea {
  border: 1px dashed;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.dragArea .dragArea > .parent {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 23px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sortablejs@1.7.0"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuedraggable@2.16.0/dist/vuedraggable.js"></script>


<script type="text/x-template" id="template-drag">
   <draggable :element="'div'" :list="tasks" class="dragArea" :options="{group:{ name:'g1'}}" > 
  <template v-for="el in tasks" class="parent">
   <div class="parent">
    <p>{{el.name}} - {{el.tasks}}</p>
    <local-draggable :tasks="el.tasks"/>
   </div>
  </template>
 </draggable>
</script>


<div id="app">       
  <local-draggable :tasks="tasks"/>
</div>
```

---

In case of, I attached the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/minuwan/nb15jd48/

Comment: i think removing position:absolute from drag area. will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

```js
var local = {
  template: '#template-drag',
  name: 'local-draggable',
  props: ['tasks']
};


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
    components: {
        "local-draggable" : local
  },
  data: {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "task 1",
       "tasks": []
    },
    {
      "name": "task 2",
       "tasks": []
    },{
      "name": "task 3",
       "tasks": []
    },
    {
      "name": "task 4",
       "tasks": []
    },
    {
      "name": "task 5",
       "tasks": []
    },
    {
      "name": "task 6",
       "tasks": [
        {
          "name": "task 6.1",
           "tasks": []
        }
       ]
    }
  ]
  },
});
```

```css
.parent{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.dragArea {
  border: 1px dashed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.dragArea .dragArea > .parent {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sortablejs@1.7.0"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuedraggable@2.16.0/dist/vuedraggable.js"></script>


<script type="text/x-template" id="template-drag">
   <draggable :element="'div'" :list="tasks" class="dragArea" :options="{group:{ name:'g1'}}" > 
  <template v-for="el in tasks" class="parent">
   <div class="parent">
    <p>{{el.name}} - {{el.tasks}}</p>
    <local-draggable :tasks="el.tasks"/>
   </div>
  </template>
 </draggable>
</script>


<div id="app">       
  <local-draggable :tasks="tasks"/>
</div>
```